# XP to Windows 7 upgrade, WITHOUT reinstalling stuff

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, upgrade

I have a bit of an emergency on my hands. Uncle needs his PC upgraded to Windows 7, however I'm not too keen on reinstalling all his programs. I can't remember if I did a clean install on my PC, but I vaguely remember reading about a method whereby one can keep all installed programs. Much like a Win 98 to XP install used to be like.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know it depends on the version of windows 7 you are installing but not having done an upgrade as I prefer a clean install I can't really give you more than that.

Comment: See Microsoft's related Help & How to page: [Upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As both the [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7) and the [Blogs DNA](http://www.blogsdna.com/3217/step-by-step-guide-to-upgrade-windows-xp-to-windows-7.htm) guide state there is no direct upgrade from XP to Windows 7 which will "transfer" installed applications from XP to 7.

> The original installation discs or setup files for the programs that you want to use with Windows 7

and

> You need to perform clean installation of Windows 7 by formatting your Windows XP or install on different hard drive partition keeping XP and Windows 7 in dual boot mode

The best you can hope for is to dual boot XP and Windows 7 and then gradually migrate applications to 7 over time. Once you've migrated everything you need you could then delete XP.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct upgrade path from XP to Windows 7. However there is a upgrade path from XP to Vista, then Vista to 7.

If you can find a copy you can upgrade to Vista, then upgrade to Windows 7 you then won't lose program access.

Comment: That sounds rather arduous. Can you add more detail about how to smooth the process, or other tips/tricks?

Comment: @Kazark He actually has a good point no one else mentioned yet, I took the liberty of fleshing out the answer a little more. Thadogg if you did not like my edit you can roll it back or make your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have resources (memory and disk space) use **virtualization**: Make a virtual copy of your XP (VMware, Qemu, etc), then Install windows 7, and run your XP programs from the windows XP virtual machine...

> and then gradually migrate applications to 7 over time. Once you've migrated everything you need you could then delete XP.

All your actual programs willl shoure work with this method, and there are several tutorials on doing **[this](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/desktop/windows7-migration.html).**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way provided by Microsoft to migrate applications.  The only option you have without reinstalling everything are [third party applications](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n2/content/view/31390/) designed for this type of movement.  However, these work with varying degrees of success by application.

http://cnettv.cnet.com/upgrade-windows-xp-to-windows-7/